# Convert string datetime filed into epoch in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have started learning PySpark recently and have some code migration task.

I have below Python script to calculate date into epoch format. Ho we can achieve this in PySpark?

```
import datetime as dt
df['Date_epoch'] = (df['Date'] - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Similar : `df = df.withColumn("Date_epoch",(F.to_timestamp("start_dt").cast("long")-
                                 F.lit(dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).cast("long")))` should do.

Comment: @anky, Thanks a lot, above script gives expected results, please add to answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp` function. It will convert string Data of most common format into timestamp.

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp)